# Moving nav when scrolling to a new anchor with fullpage.js

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, fullpage.js, slick.js

I have a long scrolling page that uses fullpage.js. The navigation has fixed positioning over the page and I have each active slide highlighting it's corresponding link.

I need the link to move into the top position when active, while still keeping the order of the remaining links, sort of like a scroll wheel you would see on iOS.

Any suggestions on the best way to make that work correctly? I have tried using slick, sort of like the following on CodePen: /DrizzlyOwl/pen/adZmem

Thanks!

Comment: [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fullpage.js callbacks](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks) such as [`onLeave`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onleave-index-nextindex-direction) to fire your JS animations, or use the [fullPage.js state classes](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) to do so with CSS.